# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2013

I had been compiling on my Visual Studio making small changes from the morning and it was running fine. I made a small change and I started getting this error,

```
error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 2
```

I removed that small change I had done. The last change I had made was adding a line to a help text.

I have absolutely no clue what this means. Can somebody please help?

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that, while adding/removing changes in your help text, you closed all tags if there are any?   I have got a similar problem when one of html tags in my help file accidentally wasn't closed .