# error MSB6006: “cmd.exe” exited with code 2 - in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, zeromq, pgm-protocol

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 2.**

Facing issue in Visual studio 2010 IDE(x64/win32- Release/Debug) even there is no configuration changes in project properties.

[I found the same issue raised earlier but there is no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620499/error-msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-2)

FYI: This issue only happens while building openPGM library using VS2010 solution. OpenPGM VS2010 solution & project files are generated by using cmake.

Answer (score 0):

If the project was build with QT (for example), you need to install it again in the new pc that you trying to run the project on.